# Putty alternative or fork with better saved session handling

Tags: ssh

I use putty and I am quite happy with it, except for the *saved sessions* feature. Since I have *a lot* of saved sessions, this tiny little window is so hard to use. Also, since it is limited in width, I have to use very short names, which makes it again more cluttered.

So basically I am searching for putty with this part being bigger and better. Optionally it could also allow for a folder structure.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout **KiTTY**. It is a fork of PuTTY, and while not the most advanced/complicated/rich, it has noticeable improvements in the line of what you're looking for.

http://www.9bis.net/kitty/?page=Welcome&zone=en

> If you need to manage a large number of sessions, with KiTTY you can
>   organize them into folders. One folder for each type of application,
>   one folder per machine, one folder per environment ... or any other
>   organisation. In the main configuration box you will find a new
>   dropdown box. By selecting a specific folder you can reduce the number
>   of sessions displayed in the selection list above.

[image]

Comment: Wow, works great. It even imported my putty config.